# How can i make a placeHolder visible while making my Datepicker component controlled( value = dateOfBirth)

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I was implementing a Datepicker in antd but i wanted the input bar to show me the placeholder but instead it shows me the initial state value here is the code

```
 <DatePicker 
        value={dateOfBirth}
        placeholder="Date of Birth"
        format={dateFormat}
        onChange={(date) => setDateOfBirth(date)} />
```

Now i wanted the placeholder to be visible at the same time i want the datepicker component to be a controlled componenent.But i couldn't make the placeholder visible unless i remove `value={dateOfBirth}` as a result which makes my component uncontrolled component. so is there any way to achieve both properties at the same time.

Comment: What initial value is being passed as the value?

Comment: const [dateOfBirth, setDateOfBirth ] = useState(moment());

Comment: You're passing a moment object as the default value, so that's why it's not displaying the placeholder. What happens if you use `null` or an empty string as the default value in `useState`?

Comment: I tried it with empty string it didn't work. But now when I try it with null as initial value it works. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I'll write up an answer for you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing a moment object as the default value, the date picker component will use that as its initial value and that's why it's not displaying the placeholder, since placeholders are only used when there is no value. You need to set the initial state value to `null`.

```
const [dateOfBirth, setDateOfBirth ] = useState(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do this, it worked for me well**

Set the initial state value to null
**`const [dateOfBirth, setDateOfBirth ] = useState(null);`**

then replace
**`placeholder="Date of Birth" with placeholderText={"Date of Birth"}`**